# GPO - Grant installation access to executables

Tags: windows-10, group-policy

I'm currently working on a project where I need to grant installation access to a group of users for all the executables located in a specific folder. I believe that utilizing Group Policy Objects (GPOs) would be an effective way to achieve this. However, I'm not entirely sure how to set up the GPO to accomplish this task.

Could someone please guide me through the necessary steps to create a GPO that allows users to install any executable file within a designated folder? Specifically, I would like to ensure that all users within a certain group have the necessary permissions to install any software located in the designated folder without requiring administrative rights.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Negative answer : Software installation in general requires administrator
permissions.

Only if the installation in question does not modify the registry or any
system folders, so that the installation is done entirely in the context
of the current user, then this is possible. Typically, such installations
basically only unzip files into some local folder.

You will need to either give this group of users administrator rights
for the duration, or disable UAC on the computer.
Both are bad ideas.

Another solution would be to create a virtual machine, where these
users can login as administrators and do these installations.
Take a backup of the VM, so you can restore it if some installation
corrupts Windows.